# Multiple combinations logic should use switch or IF

Tags: php, logic, preg-split

I am trying to write a logic when a particular string are present in switch.

Ex: String

`* * * * *` My string will alway be in this format space between each string but the string length varies. but 5 spaces and 5 string

Other examples:
`0 * * * *` 
`* 0 * * *` 
`* * 12/3 * *` 
`* * 0 0 *` 
`0 0 * * *` 
`* * * 0 0` 
`* * * AA 12`

What I am trying here is to write switch cases when the string present other then `*` i will run case.

```
switch(true):
case '0 * * * * ':
echo 'First string has value';
case '`* * 0 0 * `':
echo '3rd & 4th string has value';
case 'A B C AA 12 ':
echo 'All string has value';
```

ect...

I have many combinations but i am not sure switch is the correct way to achive it.

OR LOGIC 2:

Should I explode the string with spaces then use if condition to check 5 string?

Comment: its a matter of schematics, switch can be easier in the long run, then and if else if.  another way is to use a regx and count the matches.

Comment: `/([^*\s]+)/`  something like this that doesn't match a space or a star  https://regex101.com/

Comment: A switch is different, if 1 case matches the ones below fire as well until broken with `break`. Just explode and verify the data or if needed use a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this

```
   $total = 0;
   if( preg_match('/([^*\s]+)/', $str, $match ) ){
       $total = count( $matches[1]);
   }
    echo $total;
```

If you need to know where they match then use this instead

```
   $str = '* 0 * * *';
   if( preg_match_all('/([^*\s]+)|\s/', $str, $match ) ){
       print_r( $match )
   }
```

Result

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => ' ',
    1 => '0',
    2 => ' ',
    3 => ' ',
    4 => ' ',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => '0',
    2 => '',
    3 => '',
    4 => '',
  ),
)
```

See this way ( 0 based index ) you know what ones matched.  Matches are in array index 1, so `$match[1][n]`,

then you can just loop over that, like this

```
  $results = [];
   foreach( $match[1] as $m ){
      if( strlen($m) > 0 ){
          $results[] = "Match at pos $m";
      }
   }
```

Etc...

The advantage is that they possible combinations of  `*` and other stuff is huge, this Normalizes that, so you only have to worry about non `*` things.  Imagine putting a case of if for every possible combination, not gonna happen.

Comment: but it gives total if the string isn `* * * 1 2` and `1 2 * * *` both are 2 but in real they should go to different conditions rite?

Comment: What i am trying here is to create a script which reads crontab command and conver them in to human redable text. so there will be many possibilities in timer for `* * * * *` so should i use switch or if?

Comment: obviously,  anyway, you will never cover every possible combination of * and numbers and `\\`

Comment: just trying my best.. which ever we are using more often.. will update if i use any new :)

Comment: cant go and see crontab all the time in production.. it would be nice to see in a page where admin can access.

Comment: as an added bonus, you can even match alpha separately and handle that as an error.  `/([a-zA-Z]+)|([^*\s]+)|\s/`  ( not sure if alpha is valid in cron time, never done it. )  but then `$match[1]` is bad, `$match[2]` is the old match 1,  the `|` is or, and `(...)` is a capture group in regx.

Comment: I recommend `PREG_SET_ORDER` as fourth arg of `preg_match_all`. Gets rid of dupe output since the regex is not using capturing groups anyways.

Comment: That's true @Xorifelse  I was attempting to keep it as simple as possible, for someone that likely has never used it, to explain flags too...  And I'm not the type put something in like that and not explain it.  Also it does change the structure of the array and makes it harder to check, IMO.

Comment: i was already in a world of infinity.. u guys make is infinity square.. ha ha thanks guys.

Comment: Regx is awesome, if you haven't used it much ( its like its own language ) I encourage you to learn the basics of it, it will solve a lot of problems for you.

Answer (score 1):

A switch statement is inherently different from an if statement:

```
switch(true){
  case true:
    echo 'true';
  case false:
    echo 'false';
  case 'foo':
    echo 'foo';
}
```

So to answer your question it is likely you can't use a switch statement.
You can use regex as shown in [ArtisticPhoenix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928862/4982088), but sometimes simplicity is good as well:

```
$list = [
  '0 * * * *',
  '* 0 * * *',
  '* * 12/3 * *',
  '* * 0 0 *',
  '0 0 * * *',
  '* * * 0 0',
  '* * * AA 12',
];

foreach($list as $item){
  if(count($cron = explode(' ', $item)) == 5){
    echo "Resultset of '$item'<br>";

    foreach($cron as $v){
      echo "$v<br>";
      // So I recommend if statements here.
    }
  } else {
    echo "'$item' is not in the correct format: '". implode(', ', $cron) . "'";
  }
}
```

Comment: so nice.. will check this with my existing logic.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can/should be solved without regex.  Depending on how well you wish to write the plain English output, you can avoid using a full battery of conditions / switch cases by leveraging some smart array functions.  Consider this approach:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f9c8e6283dfe53b6d1f35c3729c5500078b63c3))

```
$strings=[
    '* * * * *',
    '0 * * * *',
    '* 0 * * *',
    '* * 12/3 * *',
    '* * 0 0 *',
    '0 0 * * *',
    '* * 0 0 0',
    '* * * AA 12',
    'A B C D E'
];
$positions=['1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th'];

foreach($strings as $s){
    $result=array_intersect_key($positions,array_diff(explode(' ',$s),['*']));
    $count=sizeof($result);
    if(!$count){
        echo "No values found in string.\n";
    }elseif($count==5){
        echo "String is full of values.\n";
    }else{
        echo "Values found in: ",implode(', ',$result),"\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
No values found in string.
Values found in: 1st
Values found in: 2nd
Values found in: 3rd
Values found in: 3rd, 4th
Values found in: 1st, 2nd
Values found in: 3rd, 4th, 5th
Values found in: 4th, 5th
String is full of values.
```

My 3 nested array functions perform like this:

1. Split the string on each space (this assumes your values will not contain a space... if this is not true, you should change your value delimiter).
2. Remove elements from the new generated array that have the value: `*` and retain the keys.
3. Referencing only elements with non-`*` values, use the keys to find the position names for displaying purposes.

This method should condense your code block substantially compared to a verbose conditional-heavy alternative.

Comment: @TomPHP I believe I have simplified and refined your task in a way superior to the other answers.  Is there something about my method that is not what you want?  With the other answers, you will still have to run a verbose battery of condition statements.  Do you want to have a different/better plain English output?